# Mentions of use of fire for cooking purpose in Hindu scriptures

Tags: food, human

Consider the following paragraphs which tell about **using fire for cooking by humans**. The act of cooking food using fire seems to be so old and important one.

[Paragraph 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_of_fire_by_early_humans)

> **The control of fire by early humans was a turning point in the
>   cultural aspect of human evolution**. Fire provided a source of warmth,
>   protection, improvement on hunting and a **method
>   for cooking food.** These cultural advances allowed human geographic
>   dispersal, cultural innovations, and changes to diet and behavior.
>   Additionally, creating fire allowed human activity to continue into
>   the dark and colder hours of the evening.

[Paragraph 2](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/people-and-culture/food/the-plate/2015/09/02/a-brief-history-of-cooking-with-fire/)

> **For most of human history, over an open fire was the one and only way to cook a meal.** People started cooking in this fashion nearly
>   two million years ago, according to anthropologist Richard Wrangham,
>   author of Catching Fire: How Cooking Made Us Human—probably, early on,
>   by simply tossing a raw hunk of something into the flames and watching
>   it sizzle.
>
> This may make modern chefs wince, but, Wrangham argues, **it was
>   likely a giant evolutionary step for mankind**, providing us not only
>   with tastier dinners, but with the extra nutrition and surplus energy
>   necessary for generating big brains (see What Makes Us Human? Cooking,
>   Study Says).

Are there any explicit mentions about cooking food using fire in Hindu scriptures?

Comment: If not by fire how will the food be cooked? :O

Comment: @Rickross haha, raw food...

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, there are mentions in Hindu scriptures on using fire for cooking.

The following paragraph from [Mahabharata](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm) is one among them which mention that people used fire for cooking the food before eating

> "And when the forest was so disturbed by the king possessed of
>   wonderful energy and by the warriors in his train delighting in
>   warlike sports, the lions began to desert it in numbers. And herds of
>   animals deprived of their leaders, from fear and anxiety began to
>   utter loud cries as they fled in all directions. And fatigued with
>   running, they began to fall down on all sides, unable to slake their
>   thirst, having reached river-beds that were perfectly dry. And many so
>   falling were eaten up by the hungry warriors. **While others were eaten
>   up after having been duly quartered and roasted in fires lit up by
>   them.** And many strong elephants, maddened with the wounds they
>   received and alarmed beyond measure, fled with trunks raised on high.
>   And those wild elephants, betraying the usual symptoms of alarm by
>   urinating and ejecting the contents of their stomachs and vomiting
>   blood in large quantities, trampled, as they ran, many warriors to
>   death. And that forest which had been full of animals, was by the king
>   with his bands of followers and with sharp weapons soon made bereft of
>   lions and tigers and other monarchs of the wilderness.'"
>
> [[Section LXIX, Sambhava Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01070.htm)